# List of all columns from syscolumns for a particular table along with the isprimarykey column in sys.indexes table

Tags: sql

I am trying to get the list of all the columns for a particular table along with the datatype and the is_primary_key column from sys.indexes table. But i am not able to get the is_primary_key column correctly. I want the is_primary_key to be set to 1 only for the column which is the primary key of the table.This is set to 1 for all the columns

Below is the query which i am using

```
select distinct c.name,c.system_type_id,is_primary_key from sys.columns c 
   inner join  sys.tables t on c.object_id=t.object_id
   inner join sys.index_columns ic on ic.column_id=c.column_id 
   inner join sys.indexes i on i.index_id=ic.index_id
   and t.name='comp' and i.is_primary_key=1
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert

```
inner join sys.indexes i on i.index_id=ic.index_id
```

to

```
inner join sys.indexes i on i.index_id=ic.index_id and i.object_id=ic.object_id
```

The primary key of `sys.indexes` is `(object_id, index_id)`. You have a similar error for `sys.index_columns`.

Answer (score 1):

```
select '['+name+']',system_type_id, case when primarykeyCol.column_id is null then 0 else 1 end primaryCol  from sys.columns c 
left join (select c.column_id from sys.indexes i  
inner join sys.index_columns ic on i.index_id = ic.index_id and i.is_primary_key = 1 and i.object_id = object_id(@srctablename) and  ic.object_id = object_id(@srctablename)
inner join sys.columns c on ic.column_id = c.column_id and c.object_id = object_id(@srctablename) 
) primarykeyCol on primarykeyCol.column_id = c.column_id 

where c.object_id = object_id(@srctablename)
```